# MacOS executable of a jar file

Tags: java, macos, jar

I have a stand alone java application that will be used in a macintosh system and I don't want to deliver the application as a jar file considering that its source code can be de-compiled. So, my intention is to convert the jar file into some sort of executable that can be run in MacOS. Is there any way to achieve this? I know that Launch4J generates the windows executable of a jar file. What I need is such a tool that enables this in MacOS. Thnaks.

Comment: *"don't want to deliver the application as a jar file .. code can be de-compiled."*  ***Anything*** can be decompiled.  Transforming a Jar into a native will not protect it.  Your best bet is probably an EULA and good lawyers.  BTW - personal impression, but it seems that those who don't realize such things are unlikely to write the type of 'killer app.' that anyone would want to steal.

Comment: OP, I don't believe what you're asking for is actually possible.

Comment: Just obfuscate it and then package it up with a JAR to OS X package bundle thingymajig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has removed the ability to create Java applications in Xcode as they are trying to have developers use Cocoa exclusively.  You could potentially get an old version of Xcode though.

If you're interested in [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/), it looks like that will create a native wrapper for your Java program for Mac OS X as well.  So if you're comfortable with that, I'd just use Launch4J.

Note that Launch4J needs some tweaks for Lion (10.7) and beyond: http://code.google.com/p/gradle-launch4j/wiki/MacOSXLion

Comment: Launch4J only creates native Windows executables. It can be run on Macs, but it won't create applications that can be run on Macs. You might consider something like this application bundler. http://java.net/projects/appbundler

Answer (score 0):

[Excelsior JET](http://www.excelsiorjet.com) is now also available for OS X.

Disclaimer: I work for Excelsior.